# Value of type 'AuthErrorCode' has no member 'debugDescription'

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

This is the code for Facebook Login on my app. The app doesn't launch and throws *Value of type 'AuthErrorCode' has no member 'debugDescription'* error. Anyone knows how I can get rid of this?

```
extension SignInViewController {
    func facebookLogin() {
        let loginManager = LoginManager()
        loginManager.logIn(permissions: [.publicProfile, .email], viewController: self) { (loginResult) in
            switch loginResult
            {
            case .cancelled:
                self.present(UIAlertController.errorAlert(with: "Cancelled"), animated: true, completion: nil)
                break
            case .failed(let error):
                print(error.localizedDescription)
                self.present(UIAlertController.errorAlert(with: error.localizedDescription), animated: true, completion: nil)
                break
            case .success(let grantedPermission, let declinedPermission, let token):
                print("the grandted permissions \(grantedPermission)")
                print("the declined  permissions \(declinedPermission)")
                print("the token is \(token)")


                let credential = FacebookAuthProvider.credential(withAccessToken: token.tokenString)


                MBProgressHUD.showAdded(to: self.view, animated: true)
                // get Facebook user information
                self.getFacebookInfo({ (appUser) in
                    if let appUser = appUser {
                        // login Firebase with Facebook
                        OAuthProvider.credential(withProviderID: "facebook.com", idToken: token.tokenString, rawNonce:self.randomNonceString())
                        Auth.auth().signIn(with: credential) { (result, error) in
                            if let error = error {
                                    MBProgressHUD.hide(for: self.view, animated: true)
                                    let castedError = error as NSError
                                let firebaseError = AuthErrorCode(AuthErrorCode.Code(rawValue: castedError.code) ?? <#default value#>)
                                if firebaseError != nil {
                                    print(firebaseError.debugDescription)
                                }
                                self.present(UIAlertController.errorAlert(with: "Signin was failed. \n\(error.localizedDescription)"), animated: true, completion: nil)
                                return
                            }
                            appUser.userId = result?.user.uid
                            self.signedInWithFacebook((result?.user)!, appUser: appUser)
                            MBProgressHUD.hide(for: self.view, animated: true)
                        }
                    } else {
                        MBProgressHUD.hide(for: self.view, animated: true)
                        self.present(UIAlertController.errorAlert(with: "Cancelled"), animated: true, completion: nil)
                    }
                })

            }
        }
    }
```

And the app doesn't build because of the below error:

```
if firebaseError != nil {
print(firebaseError.debugDescription)
}
```

*Value of type 'AuthErrorCode' has no member 'debugDescription'
*
[image]

Any help with this would be much appreciated.

Comment: Why not simply `print(firebaseError)` ? Something only has `debugDescription` if it conforms to the `CustomDebugStringConvertible` protocol.

Answer (score 0):

For an element to have a `.debugDescription` property it must have been conformed to `CustomDebugStringConvertible`. The author of the library in this case hasn't done so, and so it is not available.

If it has been conformed to `CustomStringConvertible` you will be able to `print(firebaseError.description)` but it's most likely your answer is just to `print(firebaseError)`.